# CSS - Can this fluid layout be achieved?

Tags: html, css

[image]
So what I want to achieve here is to have the red box a fixed width say 400px that is horizontally centered on the page. Either side of the red box is a green box and a lilac box of variable width that fill out the rest of the window horizontally and stretch to fit the window size.

So on a larger monitor the green and lilac boxes would be stretched horizontally and the red box in the middle of the page would remain the same width.

The solution would need to work in IE 8 and above ideally although I'm interested in solution that only work in IE9 + too.

Comment: @CBroe this question has boxes with spaces between them so although the table-cell approach works it requires further nested divs. Note this is not a white border but actual space. There is a better solution presented in the answers below. There is also a forward looking solution using Calc that is better in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `calc` to solve this:

HTML:

```
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="lilac"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%
}

.green {
    width: calc((100% - 400px)/2); //takes the total space, minus the red box space, divided by two.
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
    float: left;
}

.red {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}

.lilac {
    width: calc((100% - 400px)/2);
    height: 200px;
    background: lavender;
    float: left;
}
```

Proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/yERs7/

Comment: Good solution, but keep in mind that calc() doesn't work in some older and mobile browsers.

Comment: @RenéRoth Ah, apologies. I often forget about legacy and mobile browsers.

Comment: Don't worry, I think your solution is preferrable!

Comment: I would use this if IE8 was not an issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `display: table` and have full compatibility even with `IE8`, as you asked

Example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emCFy/

---

**Markup:**

```
<div>
  <section style="background: #91ee93">
    Green</section>
  <section style="background: #ee8c8f" role="main">
    Red</section>
  <section style="background: #e48fec">
    Pink</section>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
div {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

section {
  display: table-cell;
}

section[role] {
  width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: this is working but crucially I can't get the space either side of the red box.

Comment: you can use a padding inside section or use a white border left/right applied to the red box (see example updated)

Answer (score 2):

[I created this quick JSFiddle hack for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/Jdjpj/1/)

Basically we let those three divs float next to each other, give the middle one a fixed width and use this markup on the other two:

```
width:50%;
padding-left: 150px;
margin-left: -150px;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

and

```
width:50%;
padding-right: 150px;
margin-right: -150px;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Where 150 equals half of the middle div's width.

Comment: The middle `div` should be 400px, so half would be 200. :)

Comment: Thanks, that's working very well but needs  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;  for Firefox

Comment: @René Roth actually this doesn't work in IE 8

Comment: Then you will have to go with the fourth solution of using a table display style, if IE8 is a priority.